# How to split list of values of a dict according to list of values from another dict?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, split

I have the 2 below dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'1':['a','b','c'],'2':['a','b','c','e'],'4':['a','f','c']}
d2 = {'1':['nm','nm','st'],'2':['nm','nm','nm','nm'],'4':['st','nm','da']}
```

Each element of the values with same index, same key are 'together'. For example, for key 1, 'a' in d1 is connected to 'nm' in d2, 'b' is connected to 'nm' and 'c' is connected to 'st'.

I'm trying to split the list of values from d1 according to the list of values from d2. In my final dict, I would have:

`{key:[[all values from d1 where d2='nm'], [all values from d1 where d2='da'], [all values from d1 where d2='st']]}`

Here the result I want is for the d1, d2 example above, empty lists would be out ideally:

```
res = {'1':[['a','b'],['c']],'2':[['a','b','c','e']],'4':[['f'],['c'],['a']]}
```

Any idea how I can reach there? I have no clue how to reach there, I am aware of `groupby()` but I was not able to use it properly - not even sure that it would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

d1 = {'1':['a','b','c'],'2':['a','b','c','e'],'4':['a','f','c']}
d2 = {'1':['nm','nm','st'],'2':['nm','nm','nm','nm'],'4':['st','nm','da']}

result = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    for m, n in groupby(zip(v, d2[k]), lambda x: x[1]):
        result.setdefault(k, []).append([s for s, _ in n])
print(result)
```

---

Or using just `dict.setdefault`

```
result = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    temp = {}
    for m, n in zip(v, d2[k]):
        temp.setdefault(n, []).append(m)
    result[k] = list(temp.values())
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': [['a', 'b'], ['c']],
 '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']],
 '4': [['a'], ['f'], ['c']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to above just slightly different. Also uses group by and zip to get your output.

```
from itertools import groupby
d1 = {'1':['a','b','c'],'2':['a','b','c','e'],'4':['a','f','c']}
d2 = {'1':['nm','nm','st'],'2':['nm','nm','nm','nm'],'4':['st','nm','da']}
d3 = {}

for key in d1:
    d3[key] = [[e[0] for e in group] for _, group in groupby(zip(d1[key], d2[key]), key=lambda x: x[1])]

print(d3)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [['a', 'b'], ['c']], '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']], '4': [['a'], ['f'], ['c']]}
```